# "Unsupported OP_QUERY command: insert" in Elixir project when trying to insert into Mongo DB

Tags: database, mongodb, elixir

I have a Mix project and I am trying to insert some data into my local database.

I have added the Mongo dependency to my project, then added the lines of code for connecting to the database and for storing data into it.

```elixir
{:ok, pid} =
  Mongo.start_link(
    url: "mongodb://localhost:27017/tweet_processor")
    
{:ok, result} =
  Mongo.insert_one(pid, "tweets", tweet_to_insert)
```

But I keep getting

```elixir
{:error, %Mongo.Error{
  code: 352,
  host: nil,
  message: "command failed: Unsupported OP_QUERY command: insert"}}
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wild guess (out of the shape of commands you’ve shared) that you are using [`mongodb`](https://github.com/elixir-mongo/mongodb) package. It explicitly states it supports MongoDB versions 2.6÷4.0. I also wild guess you are using MongoDB 5+ backend, which has `OP_QUERY` [explicitly deprecated](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/mongodb-wire-protocol/#request-opcodes).

The driver you use is OSS, and from its source code, one might see that `Mongo.insert_one/4` [delegates](https://github.com/elixir-mongo/mongodb/blob/master/lib/mongo.ex#L676) to [low-level call](https://github.com/elixir-mongo/mongodb/blob/6ae204966e0842c852466431c9fcb06056e1ceb9/lib/mongo.ex#L630) which issues `OP_QUERY`.

One possibility to fix the issue would be to downgrade MongoDB to v4.0, another (most appreciated by a community) would be to provide a PR to the library, supporting MongoDB 5+.

Answer (score 1):

Update mongo-java-driver version and try again

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
   <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
   <version>3.12.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error. "Unsupported OP_QUERY command: insert" For me this ended up being an issue with **Mongoose**. After upgrading mongoose to ^6.5.2 it works without issue.

With NPM you can update the package like so:

```
npm install mongoose@6.5.2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use [this driver](https://hex.pm/packages/mongodb_driver) which has support for MongoDB 5.x